# stri_split_fixed in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, stringi

I have a data.table `DT` as follows.

```
DT <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("S01", "S02", "S03" ), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Alan Hal << Guy John", "Bruce Dick Jean-Paul << Damien", "Jay << Barry Wally Bart"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
# DT
#    V1                             V2
# 1 S01           Alan Hal << Guy John
# 2 S02        Jay << Barry Wally Bart
# 3 S03 Bruce Dick Jean-Paul << Damien
setDT(DT)
```

I am trying to split the column `V2` at "<<" and the get the output in two new columns.

I could get it done as follows using `stringi`

```
T <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,  stri_split_fixed(DT$V2, "<<", 2)))
setnames(T, old = colnames(T), new = c("V3", "V4"))
cbind(DT, T)
V1                             V2                    V3                V4
1: S01           Alan Hal << Guy John             Alan Hal           Guy John
2: S02        Jay << Barry Wally Bart                  Jay   Barry Wally Bart
3: S03 Bruce Dick Jean-Paul << Damien Bruce Dick Jean-Paul             Damien
```

However I would like to do the same by reference using the `:=` operator. How to do this using data.table?

I am having difficulty with the RHS part.

```
DT[, c("V1", "V2) := list()]
```

`stri_split_fixed(DT$V2, "<<", 2)` gives a list of 3 with character vectors of length 2. How to get a list of 2 with character vectors of length 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
setDT(DT)[, c('V3', 'V4'):=do.call(rbind.data.frame,
                    stri_split_fixed(V2, ' << ', 2))][]
#  V1                             V2                    V3                V4
#1: S01           Alan Hal << Guy John             Alan Hal           Guy John
#2: S02        Jay << Barry Wally Bart                  Jay   Barry Wally Bart
#3: S03 Bruce Dick Jean-Paul << Damien Bruce Dick Jean-Paul             Damien
```

Or you could use `strsplit` (from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
 setDT(DT)[, c('V3', 'V4'):= do.call(rbind.data.frame,
                   strsplit(as.character(V2), " << "))]
```

More efficient option (as suggested by @Ananda Mahto)

```
cbind(DT, `colnames<-`(stri_split_fixed(DT$V2,
              " << ", simplify = TRUE), c("V3", "V4")))
```

Another option would be to use `cSplit` from [`splitstackshape`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/splitstackshape.pdf)

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(DT, 'V2', ' << ', stripWhite=FALSE, drop=FALSE)
#       V1                             V2                 V2_1             V2_2
#1: S01           Alan Hal << Guy John             Alan Hal         Guy John
#2: S02        Jay << Barry Wally Bart                  Jay Barry Wally Bart
#3: S03 Bruce Dick Jean-Paul << Damien Bruce Dick Jean-Paul           Damien
```

A faster version of `cSplit` which gives similar performance as `stri_split` is available in [`Gist`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3865d516fcc575d7099c)

Comment: You don't need `stringi` for this.. Just `setDT(DT)[, c('V3', 'V4'):= do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(as.character(V2), " << "))]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was just copying the code of the OP.  Yes, it is not really needed.  But, by specifying `fixed`, I think it might be faster

Comment: I like the third approach :-) ... Nice syntax and decent performance. But I'm not impressed by the first two options. I would do `cbind(DT, `colnames<-`(stri_split_fixed(DT$V2, " << ", simplify = TRUE), c("V3", "V4")))`. The difference *should* be huge. By the way, the next version of `cSplit` would be using `stri_split_*`, so the `cSplit` approach would come closer to this suggestion in the comment.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I get a NA column and the ` << <<` in the original column using `cSplit`.  Obviously, I didn't show the output :-)  Thanks for the other option

Comment: I think you meant to use `stripWhite = FALSE`. It's a problem in my existing function to strip whitespace.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Yes, that solves the problem.  Now, I can show the output :-)

Comment: A rough-cut [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3865d516fcc575d7099c) of `cSplit` that should give similar performance to the raw `stri_split` approach.